# auto.arima() function suggesting ARIMA(2,0,0) when time series is non-stationary

Tags: r, time-series

I am currently working on a time series of VALE3.SA https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/VALE3.SA/history?p=VALE3.SA .

On R, the auto.arima() function from package forecast returns me ARIMA(2,0,0). But when i use adf.test() and pp.test() they indicate non-stationarity. I also tried diff() and it turns my series into stationary, but when i try to force auto.arima to use 1 differenciation it suggests ARIMA(0,1,0). What model should I use? Is ARIMA(2,0,0) even valid without stationarity?

````
auto <- auto.arima(tsvale[,"Close"])

ARIMA(2,0,0) with non-zero mean 

Coefficients:
         ar1      ar2     mean
      1.1156  -0.1518  35.9059
s.e.  0.0739   0.0742   6.0635

sigma^2 estimated as 10.89:  log likelihood=-464.95
AIC=937.91   AICc=938.14   BIC=950.63 ```


> adf.test(tsvale[,"Close"])

    Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  tsvale[, "Close"]
Dickey-Fuller = -2.2874, Lag order = 5, p-value = 0.4561
alternative hypothesis: stationary

> pp.test(tsvale[,"Close"])

    Phillips-Perron Unit Root Test

data:  tsvale[, "Close"]
Dickey-Fuller Z(alpha) = -8.1416, Truncation lag parameter = 4, p-value = 0.649
alternative hypothesis: stationary```



auto.arima(tsvale[,"Close"], d = 1)
Series: tsvale[, "Close"] 
ARIMA(0,1,0) 

sigma^2 estimated as 11.13:  log likelihood=-464.39
AIC=930.78   AICc=930.8   BIC=933.96 ```
````